# Developing oauth 2.0 authorization server in php

Tags: php

Which php framework has been used in developing the tutorial in http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/developing-an-oauth2-authorization-server/.
I initially thought it was **Codeigniter** but after reading the code, it's different. Especially the ***Session::get*** part of the code.

Comment: Alex Bilbie seems to answer the comments on his blog. Why don't you ask him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being developed in Laravel it appears to me.... I believe it is using the bundle oauth2-server.  You can find the information at [Laravels](http://www.laravel.com/) Website  and the [bundle](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/oauth2-server) website

Because of the use of composer in the tutorial.  I would almost say it is actually using [Laravel 4](http://four.laravel.com) which will not use the bundle I said previously but use the package described in the tutorial.